# Appending div to div in phonegap with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am learning to develop apps with phonegap. My problem is that at the moment of appending a div, it doesnt show as it should.

Here is part of my code

```
<div data-role="content" id="contenido">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="tareas">

    <div data-role="collapsible" id="tarea_1">'+
        '<h3>Tarea 1</h3>'+
        '<a class="ui-btn-a ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" data-form="ui-btn-up-a" data-swatch="a" data-theme="a" href="#">Descripcion</a>        </div>

    </div>             
 </div>
```

this collapsible "tarea_1", if I add it into the HTML it will appear like this.

[image: Dreamweaver preview]

But when I append it with this code:

```
$('#tareas').append('<div data-role="collapsible" id="tarea_1">'+
        '<h3>Tarea 1</h3>'+
        '<a class="ui-btn-a ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" data-form="ui-btn-up-a" data-swatch="a" data-theme="a" href="#">Descripcion</a>          </div>').listview('refresh');
```

This is what I get

[image: View on the phone]

I thought it was because of the refresh, but I cant figure out how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ".collapsibleset('refresh');" instead of ".listview('refresh')"

See this example  [for Jquery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/examples/collapsibles/dynamic-collapsible.html#&ui-state=dialog)

Working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/upNWd0s9fBRPZJgZEyXQ?p=preview)

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
  $('#tareas').append("<div data-role='collapsible' id='tarea1'><h3>Tarea 1</h3></div>").collapsibleset('refresh'); 
});
```